# Selenium 3.4.0 with Firefox 55

Tags: selenium, firefox, geckodriver

yesterday my Firefox browser updated to 55. Since then my code wont work any more. Im using Selenium 3.4  geckodriver 18.0 and Firefox 55. In chrome it works. i got the following message:

```
> 1503585931231 geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.18.0
> 1503585931265 geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:31895
> 1503585932805 geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser C:\Program
> Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe with args ["-marionette"]
> 1503585936703 Marionette  INFO    Enabled via --marionette Unable to read
> VR Path Registry from
> C:\Users\Ja\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath [GPU 2512]
> WARNING: pipe error: 109: file
> c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc,
> line 346 1503585942553    Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 49243
> 1503585943132 Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 49243
> 1503585943228 Marionette  DEBUG   loaded listener.js Aug 24, 2017 4:45:43
> PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
> INFORMATION: Detected dialect: W3C
> 1503585944268 Marionette  DEBUG   Received DOM event "beforeunload" for
> "about:blank" 1503585945049   Marionette  DEBUG   Received DOM event
> "pagehide" for "about:blank" 1503585945051    Marionette  DEBUG   Received
> DOM event "unload" for "about:blank"
> 1503585945102 Marionette  DEBUG   Received DOM event "DOMContentLoaded"
> for "http://www.phptravels.net/"
> 1503585945208 Marionette  DEBUG   Received DOM event "pageshow" for
> "http://www.phptravels.net/" 1503585970177    Marionette  INFO    New
> connections will no longer be accepted Aug 24, 2017 4:46:13 PM
> org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess destroy SCHWERWIEGEND: Unable to
> kill process with PID 11736
```

Has somebody the same problem and maybe a solution? or should I just downgrade Firefox?

Forget to say that iam working with Selenium WebDriver.

Thanks for answering.

Comment: Post a issue with geckodriver or marrionette. Might be they are not working on FF55 as of now and as a workaround go back to 54

Answer (score 8):

https://www.katalon.com might be a good alternative. It's free, but not Open Source.
But it is not compatible to Selenium, i.e. test cases created with Selenium IDE cannot run with Katalon.

Answer (score 3):

Katalon is a very good choice. If you want more alternatives, as said in [Top 3 Selenium IDE alternatives for Firefox & Chrome](https://www.katalon.com/resources-center/blog/selenium-ide-alternative-firefox-chrome/), look into those:

1. Katalon Recorder with [Firefox addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/katalon-automation-record/) or [Chrome addon](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/katalon-recorder-selenium/ljdobmomdgdljniojadhoplhkpialdid)
2. Protractor, you can use [protractor recorder npm package](https://github.com/ealves/protractor-recorder)
3. Robot Framework (only supporting [Chrome addon](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-robot/dihdbpkpgdkioobahfpnkondnekhbmlo?hl=en) by now)

Answer (score 1):

Bad news: from Firefox 55 onwards, Selenium IDE will no longer work.
Check: https://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/2017/08/09/firefox-55-and-selenium-ide/

Answer (score 1):

I did help myself so far with Firefox Portable v54:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/portableapps/files/Mozilla%20Firefox%2C%20Portable%20Ed./Mozilla%20Firefox%2C%20Portable%20Edition%2054.0.1/

It works parallel with other versions of FF.

To disable automatic update of this installation *never* go to Help->About screen. Rather do 2 things:

- in the settings set "never check for updates"
- If you want to know the active version type about:support in the address bar.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium is having a compatibility issue with firefox version 55+

*Issue for reference: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4406.*

What you can do right now is revert back your firefox to 54.0.1, for that you can

1. 1st uninstall 55+ version and the maintenance service
2. download the 54.0.1 installer
3. while installing choose custom install and then disable maintenance service which auto updates the version to the latest.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using Katalon Automation Recorder. I found it to be a great Selenium IDE alternative solution. As mention above, it's an addon work on both Chrome and FF Quantum.

I was able to import my existing Selenium IDE projects into Katalon Automation Recorder. Here the [guide](https://forum.katalon.com/discussion/4175/import-recorded-test-case-into-katalon-automation-recorder) Katalon team provided.

Comment: Generally, links to a tool or library [should be accompanied by usage notes, a 
specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, or some 
sample code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605), or if possible all of the above.

Answer (score 0):

From August 2018, [Selenium IDE Is Dead, Long Live Selenium IDE](https://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/2018/08/06/selenium-ide-tng/)!

Official docs are [here](https://www.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/getting-started/).